# List has a date and amount, I need to create a cumulative amount by date

Tags: list-manipulation

I have a list which has a date and a amount, I need to create a list that has the cummulative total with the date.

I have the following result:

```
{{{2009, 8, 3}, 1829.}, {{2009, 8, 4}, 1113.}, {{2009, 8, 5}, 730.}, {{2009, 8, 6}, -243.}}
```

What I need:

```
 {{{2009, 8, 3}, 1829.}, {{2009, 8, 4}, 2942.}, {{2009, 8, 5}, 3672.}, {{2009, 8, 6}, 3429.}}
```

I have just spent over an hour trying to figure this out, any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
list = {{{2009, 8, 3}, 1829.}, {{2009, 8, 4}, 1113.}, {{2009, 8, 5},730.}, {{2009, 8, 6}, -243.}}

Rest@FoldList[{#2[[1]], (#1 + #2)[[2]]} &, 0, list]
```

Or

```
Rest@FoldList[{#2[[1]], Last@Plus@## } &, 0, list]
```

Comment: Thank you, they both work great. Since I have worked with FoldList before I will go with this one.

Comment: @John `Transpose` and `Accumulate` (both used in b.gatessucks' answer) are very useful functions. If you are not using them yet, you should :)

Answer (score 17):

Something like :

```
alist = {{{2009, 8, 3}, 1829.}, {{2009, 8, 4}, 1113.}, {{2009, 8, 5},730.}, {{2009, 8, 6}, -243.}};

Transpose[{alist[[All, 1]], Accumulate[alist[[All, 2]]]}]
```

Comment: @acheong87 Running my code reproduces the requested output; do you get anything different ?

Comment: My mistake; somehow I was getting a list of dates, and a list of cumulative values; my input must have gotten mucked up somewhere. Deleting my comment; already +1'ed.

Answer (score 5):

Starting with:

```
list = {{{2009, 8, 3}, 1829.}, {{2009, 8, 4}, 1113.}, {{2009, 8, 5}, 730.}, {{2009, 8, 6}, -243.}};
```

I propose:

```
MapAt[Accumulate, list\[Transpose], 2]\[Transpose]
```

Which in the Notebook looks like:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or with in-place modification:

```
list[[All, 2]] = Accumulate @ list[[All, 2]]; list
```